# Update oracle CLOB column with large string

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc, clob, lob

I have a table `systesttab` that contains a few columns. One of those columns is of type CLOB and it's supposed to hold a string of a base64 encoded image.

```
CREATE TABLE systesttab(
    ...
    f_picture     CLOB       DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

However, when I try to update the table with a large base64 string (over 100k character), it fails and my python application crashes (even when put in a try...except block).

```
UPDATE systesttab SET f_picture = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoASU ...'
```

I have even tried to cast the value to clob:

```
UPDATE systesttab SET f_picture = TO_CLOB('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoASU ...')
```

But all I get is this error:

**`Input string too long, limit 8192`**

Now, I guess that this is trying to tell me something about the chunk size, but it's not really helpful to me.

[image]

How can I update the table with a single statement?

Do I have to declare the table's create statement differently?

If there is a way to get this done in a single statement, it should also work when updating multiple columns on the same table.

Environment: python 3.4 & pyodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using SQL Bindings. It seems the character limit does not apply then.

In python the statement now looks like this:

```
pic = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoASU ...'
sql = "UPDATE systesttab SET f_picture = ?"
cursor.execute( sql, [pic] )
```

This also works fine when updating multiple fields at the same time.